# Calling a function once when data enters in d3

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to call a function when data enters using data().enter()?

For example, in this current jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3m8A/4/ , I have a function that draws a group and I want to call this function when new data enters. The current jsfiddle doesn't do anything but the objective is to click on the red square and using .data.enter draw a purple square when the red square is clicked.

The specific part I'm trying to get to work is :

```
canvas.selectAll("#boxGroup")
    .data(data)
.enter().function(d,i) {
    drawBox(150,20,d);
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want the method `.call(function(d))`

This will run your function once, passing `d` as the array of all of the data you have provided. `i` is not defined for using `call` after `enter()`.

If you want to draw multiple boxes, based on `d`, your code would look something like this:

```
canvas.selectAll("boxGroup")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .call(function(d){drawBoxes(150,20,d);});
```

I've created a basic fiddle of this [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/PVufB/)

Note that this is what you want to use if you want to call a function on the selection returned by `.enter()` in the same spot as you're using it. It's also possible to bind a function to the `enter` event of a given DOM element by using `.on('enter',function)`, but this would require that the element that you are entering data into already exist.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, because the call method gives the selection, not the datum bound to each selection. See my answer below.

Answer (score 14):

The callback passed to the call method is actually passed the selection, not the data.

```
enterSelection.call(function(selection){/* this === selection */});
```

So, what you were probably looking for is the each method.

```
enterSelection.each(function(d,  i){/* this is selection */ drawBoxes(150,20,d);});
```